# I'm trying to do a masked text effect that reveals like this one

Tags: masking

I'm trying to do a simple mask to reveal text like this one. It has a soft gradient on the mask and the text is moving up as it is revealed. I know how to do this in After Effects, but I'm new to Blender. Any help would be appreciated. I also need to animate in the line coming from the text to the bottle, but I'm guessing that will be pretty much the same technique?

[image: Text Masked Reveal]

Comment: I have something similar -- I animate the text to come through the background plane (yellow in your case) that is at an angle so that less and less of the text is eclipsed.  Oddly there is no way to add a Mask modifier to Text, and even if possible would require sets of vertices (groups) assigned to Masks with different vertex group Weights or Threshhold animations.